# Solr: Exact query syntax for synonyms?

Tags: indexing, solr, synonym

I modified the techproducts example to learn more about synonyms. The added field has the type text2_de

```
<fieldType name="text2_de" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
     <analyzer type="index">
         <tokenizer class="solr.ClassicTokenizerFactory"/>
         <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/> 
         <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" format="snowball" words="lang/stopwords_de.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
         <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
         <tokenizer class="solr.ClassicTokenizerFactory"/>
         <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/> 
    </analyzer>
```

The index_synonyms.txt was expanded by hierarchical synonyms starting with a level for faceting according https://wiki.apache.org/solr/HierarchicalFaceting

```
aaafoo => aaabar
bbbfoo => bbbfoo bbbbar
cccfoo => cccbar cccbaz
fooaaa,baraaa,bazaaa

Umwelt => 1/HS , 2/HS/Bereich , 3/HS/Bereich/Umwelt
Mensch => 1/HS , 2/HS/Bereich , 3/HS/Bereich/Mensch
...
```

The loaded term info shows, that the analyzer works very well and found 60x "2/hs/bereich" in a document set.

[loaded term info for the testfield](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyV5T.jpg)

I'm not able to make a solr-query to find these 60 documents. The auto generated hyperlink of the loaded term info

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/#/test/query?q=testfield:2%2Fhs%2Fbereich
```

found no matches (numFound="0"):

```
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
  <int name="status">0</int>
  <int name="QTime">0</int>
  <lst name="params">
    <str name="q">testfield:2/hs/bereich</str>
    <str name="indent">on</str>
    <str name="wt">xml</str>
    <str name="_">1463321610566</str>
  </lst>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="0" start="0">
</result>
</response>
```

Please give me a tip to make an exact solr query syntax for synonyms to find these 60 documents!

Answer (score 0):

Solution found: Please add wildcards in the auto generated query of the loaded term info in this example: **testfield:*2/hs/strahlung***

```
<response>
 <lst name="responseHeader">
  <int name="status">0</int>
  <int name="QTime">24</int>
  <lst name="params">
    <str name="q">*:*</str>
    <str name="facet.field">testfield</str>
    <str name="indent">on</str>
    <str name="facet.prefix">3/hs/strahlung</str>
    <str name="fq">testfield:*2/hs/strahlung*</str>
    <str name="rows">0</str>
    <str name="facet">on</str>
    <str name="wt">xml</str>
    <str name="_">1463590654764</str>
  </lst>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="68" start="0">
</result>
<lst name="facet_counts">
  <lst name="facet_queries"/>
  <lst name="facet_fields">
    <lst name="testfield">
      <int name="3/hs/strahlung/neutronen">44</int>
      <int name="3/hs/strahlung/wirkung">37</int>
      <int name="3/hs/strahlung/strahlensschutz">34</int>
      <int name="3/hs/strahlung/exposition">22</int>
      <int name="3/hs/strahlung/radioaktivitaet">22</int>
      <int name="3/hs/strahlung/radiologisch">12</int>
      <int name="3/hs/strahlung/strahlenart">7</int>
    </lst>
  </lst>
  <lst name="facet_ranges"/>
  <lst name="facet_intervals"/>
  <lst name="facet_heatmaps"/>
</lst>
</response>
```

In combination with the facet.prefix **3/hs/strahlung** it was possible to drill down the question for the hierarchical synonyms.